# Why "DISCOVERY_FINISHED" Message printed twice?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I want to Search Bluetooth Device Every three seconds.
so, I used Timer like this.

```
    public void SearchingDevice() {
    m_BTAdapter.startDiscovery();

    m_timer = new Timer(true);              
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            m_BTAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            m_BTAdapter.startDiscovery();
        }
    };
    m_timer.schedule(timerTask, 3000, 3000);
}
```

By the way, "android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_FINISHED" Message
always printed twice..... why this message printed twice??
I used cancelDiscovery() only once...
please someone help me..!!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful with timer task. Maybe the problem is that you are not canceling task with activityLifecycle and each time you are creating a new one.
try:

```
@Override
 protected void onPause() {
   super.onPause();
   m_timer.cancel();
}
```

can you paste the piece of code where you call SearchingDevice() method?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: but.. i can't paste the piece of code.. 
An error has occurred